# Populate a column1 of Table1 with data from column2 from Table2 dynamically using only Excel formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a dashboard that shows a certain amount of data in tables (Column ID in black table).
This dashboard is locked and cannot be edited (manually). I want to update the black table with data from my datasheet (Column ID in yellow table) dynamically. My datasheet table has more rows than my dashboard table and thus needs to be extended. I am having a hard time figuring out how to tackle this problem using **ONLY** excel formulas, VBA will be my last resort as there will be many more tables using the data from the datasheet.

[image: Left: My dashboard on some sheet. Right: My Datasheet in some other sheet.]

I have tried several structured references trying to fill columns in my dashboard:
`=Datasheet[@ID]` Results in #Value! Error
`=Datasheet[[#Data];[ID]:[ID]` Results in #Spill! Error and neither append rows to the table.

Comment: There are two issues: 1) you can't use spill-formulas in tables. 2) your dashboard sheet is locked - then the table will never resize. What you can do: use the second formula on the dashboard sheet - but not within a table

Comment: In this example i have not locked the table yet it wont resize. I found that using the second formula in empty cells that is does copy all the data.  Unfortunately it does not work in tables. Im guessing i will have to write a macro for this problem.